# Question about goroutine with cond and waitgroup

Tags: go, goroutine

Please explain why the there is a groutineRunning waitGroup inside the subscribe function and why it is needed.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    type Button struct {
        Clicked *sync.Cond
    }

    button := Button{Clicked: sync.NewCond(&sync.Mutex{})}

    subscribe := func(c *sync.Cond, fn func()) {
        var goroutineRunning sync.WaitGroup
        goroutineRunning.Add(1)
        go func() {
            goroutineRunning.Done()
            c.L.Lock()
            defer c.L.Unlock()
            c.Wait()
            fn()
        }()
        goroutineRunning.Wait()
    }

    var clickRegistered sync.WaitGroup
    clickRegistered.Add(3)

    subscribe(button.Clicked, func() {
        fmt.Println("Maximizing window.")
        clickRegistered.Done()
    })

    subscribe(button.Clicked, func() {
        fmt.Println("Displaying annoying dialog box!")
        clickRegistered.Done()
    })

    subscribe(button.Clicked, func() {
        fmt.Println("Mouse clicked.")
        clickRegistered.Done()
    })

    button.Clicked.Broadcast()
    clickRegistered.Wait()
}
```

I was expecting the code to still work when I remove the waitgroup inside the function.

Comment: It looks like it is there to make sure the inner go-routine is started. Using a channel and a bit refactoring could improve the code

Comment: It doesn't technically work with the waitgroup as shown either, the `subscribe` function could still return before `goroutineRunning.Done` is called. The point should be to wait for the lock to be held.

Answer (score 0):

Without the `goroutineRunning` waitgroup, the goroutine doesn't actually get scheduled before the call to `button.Clicked.Broadcast()`.  `Broadcast()` is notifying all goroutines currently waiting on the condition, which is none. Then, the goroutine gets scheduled afterwards, and is locking .. so you get a deadlock.

Without getting into whether a `sync.Cond` is the right solution for the problem, almost anything that ensures the goroutine gets scheduled before the condition is locked should work.

For example (see [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/kw8DAO7ld9i)):

```golang
    subscribe := func(c *sync.Cond, fn func()) {
        go func() {
            c.L.Lock()
            defer c.L.Unlock()
            c.Wait()
            fn()
        }()

        // Schedule the goroutine to ensure the lock happens before returning.
        // This sort of works because of the FIFO run queues, but might
        // still be susceptible to race hazards 
        runtime.Gosched()
    }
```

What you really want to ensure is that the lock has definitely happened, so probably something like this is actually safer:

```golang
    subscribe := func(c *sync.Cond, fn func()) {
        var isLocked sync.WaitGroup
        isLocked.Add(1)
        go func() {
            c.L.Lock()
            isLocked.Done()

            defer c.L.Unlock()
            c.Wait()
            fn()
        }()
        isLocked.Wait()
    }
```

That feels kind of messy, but hopefully makes it clear what's actually going wrong when just removing the waitgroup.